# probability of fourth ball is black

Tags: probability

suppose that  bag contains $3$ red and $5$  black ball,each ball one by one,without replacement is selected at random,what is a probability that fourth ball is  black?probability from the beginning of red ball is $3/8$ and black one is $5/8$,but after  third  selection,how could we determine  how much black left?we only know that $5$ ball left,but what about amount of black?should we try all of combination?for example if all three is red,then probability of black  on fourth selection is $5/5=1$,but if all  three is black,then probability is $2/5$,please help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you need to do is to consider the number of arrangements of RRRBBBBB where B denotes a black ball and R denotes a red ball. The number of arrangements is $x=\frac{8!}{3!5!}$. However if we fix B at the 4th position we will have $y=\frac{7!}{3!4!}$ arrangements.

Thus the probability of getting a black ball at the 4th pick is $\frac yx$.

Comment: Very nice answer!

Comment: so why fix?what does mean fix in this  situation?

Comment: we fix one of the B's in the 4th position so that we are guaranteed to draw a black ball at the 4th pick

Comment: what does also  $8!/3!*5!\$ express?number of selection   of all ball from $8$ ball?

Comment: $\frac{8!}{5!3!}$ expresses the number of arrangements of the characters RRRBBBBB

Comment: where $3$! is for red and $5$! for black right

Comment: yes that's right

Comment: now about fixing,could you explain it more detail

Comment: We are considering the case wherein the 4th ball picked is black. Thus we want an arrangement wherein a B in the 4th position. Thus we fix one of the B's in the 4th position. The rest can then be arranged without restriction

Comment: as i understood  $8!/(3!*5!)$,is all  selection ball from  $8$ ball,does order  matter?

Comment: yes $\frac{8!}{5!3!}$ is the set of all possible arrangements of the 8 balls without restriction. what do you mean by does order matter?

Comment: i mean permutation or combination

Comment: about fourth place,i am big confused,let us say  what is  a  all possible arrangement that fourth place is black,it could be  $3$ red and fourth black,$2$ red and third and fourth  black,all first four black,first red and  all three  black,two black and  third red and fourth black,what is a total  amount of possibility of such  selection?

Comment: it is a permutation with repetition of indistinguishable objects... something similar to this: http://www.regentsprep.org/Regents/math/ALGEBRA/APR2/LpermRep.htm

Comment: well the reason i fixed B in the 4th place is so that then the remaining 7 balls (RRRBBBB) may be arranged without restriction thus we have $\frac{7!}{4!3!}$

Answer (score 1):

Since you'e picking the balls at random, without replacement, just decide before you start that you'll put the first ball you pick in the #4 slot.

So, the probability of a black in Slot #4 is $\frac{5}{3+5}=0.625$

Or, think of it this way:  what are the odds that the **first** ball you pick is black?  Clearly, it's the same $0.625.$  But then, after picking all eight and putting them down in normal 1, 2, 3, ... order,  you take the last three and move them (without rearranging) to the front!  Now, that black is in Slot #4...